# Refresh component from another component

Tags: angular

in Angular I want to refresh one component from another component.

I saw this article

https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/refresh-angular-component-without-navigation-148a87c2de3f

which suggest to add

```
mySubscription: any;
```

Then to add following in the constructor of my component.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
};

this.mySubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  // Trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
  this.router.navigated = false;
  }
});
```

And make sure to unsubscribe to "mySubscription" like below

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 if (this.mySubscription) {
   this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

but I don't understand it because there is no information about in which component should I add this, and how to trigger the refresh on button click event.. If someone can help I will be so grateful !

Comment: Im not so sure this will actually solves your problem, do you need to refresh component `B` if you click a button on component `A`? If yes, then why you need to refresh it

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress I'm fetching protocols from my server and I render it in two component (I import the same service in both). But when I add a new protocol in component A, I want it to update also in component B without having to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

So if you have two components let's say `componentA` and `componentB` and if you want some data sync between two component I'd go for a shared service

[here is a example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-http-otdt75-nxfwep?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for you to understand the below explanation.

for EX: ill call it `ProductService`

```js
export class ProductService {
  private _producturl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  private _addNewSubject = new Subject();
  private _addNew$ = this._addNewSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getproducts(): Observable < IProduct[] > {
    return this._http.get(this._producturl)
      .map((response: Response) => < IProduct[] > response.json())
      .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }

  public get addNew$() {
    return this._addNew$;
  }

  public addNew(newItem: IProduct) {
    this._addNewSubject.next(newItem);
  }
}
```

`_addNewSubject`  is a subject, by subscribing to that subject both component can get latest data.

how to subscribe?

```js
this._product.addNew$.subscribe(newItem => this.iproducts = [...this.iproducts, newItem]);
```

This subscribe will call when someone executes the `addNew` function in the service, and using `newItem`  param you can get the data, that pushed inside the `addNew` function using `this._addNewSubject.next(newItem);`

Comment: Thank you for the response ! I'm gonna try and understand this code. By the way the stackblitz link doesn't work for me if you have another ? BR

Comment: I am still stuck with this .. :( is there a chance I send you my code so you can explain me better based on my situation ?

Comment: How the addNew function using next() could help me adding a product to the db ?